# Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'Quality' at row 1

Tags: mysql, double

Below is the MySQL code for the row that the error is for:

```
Quality DOUBLE(1,1)
```

I put `2.0` in the `quality` field and got the error:

> Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'Quality' at row 1
>
> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'Quality' at row 1

Comment: trying to create a table?

Comment: There is a table i just show the relevant part

Comment: Well the DOUBLE( lenght, decimal), your lenght is too small so the input overflows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You column `Quality DOUBLE(1,1)` can take input only 1 |2 |3

`Double( totalsize, decimal)`, size is the number of characters.
Since your field length is small, the input overflows.
Update your table to fix this.

Comment: Do it like Double( 16,4 ) etc

Comment: Does 16 mean, characters before the decimal and 4 is characters after the decimal so 1234567891011121.1234